# any rule for knowing when python built-in methods will return something?

Tags: python

For example,`'somestring '.strip()` will return the string with the trailing space stripped. However, `[1, 2, 3].sort()` will return `None`. Is there a rule or something to help know when a built-in method will return something and when it will not?

Or do I just need to memorize them?

Comment: If it mutates the object it returns None.

Comment: @Anonymous: Not always. See Ethos' answer for a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to refer to the documentation quite often (or you can memorize them if you're able to, as you said). However, there is a rule of thumb you've neglected to notice (perhaps).

Take both your examples:

```
'somestring '.strip() # string method
[1, 2, 3].sort() # list method
```

Notice that strings are immutable and lists are mutable. The consequence is that for immutable objects a method *must* return a new object you can assign to a variable. Mutable objects, however, tend to return `None` because in essence there's no need to return the object--it's just being modified in-place.

An exception to this, for example, is the `.pop()` method for lists, which happens to return the object removed from the list.

Comment: Because `list.pop()` returns the pop'ped value, as well as mutating the list. And `list.index()/count()` return values because they're queries/searches. All other list methods' results are simply the mutated list itself.

Answer (score 1):

Alongside the @Eithos's answer, You can use `type()` function.Simply the type of the result of in-place bilt-in functions that returns None is None :

```
>>> type([].sort())
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> type(''.strip())
<type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 1):

There a few answers that are possible:

1. Read the manuals, (and remember the ones that you use often).
2. In a python shell, ipython or debugger try the thing that you are thinking of using and see what it returns
3. In a python shell use help(*someobject*) - quick way to read the manual
4. In ipython use *something*`?` to be told more about *something* - ditto
5. Some IDEs e.g.: [Wing](http://wingware.com/) have a code hinting tool that shows the help as you type.
6. Run [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) on your code it is good at spotting this sort of error